# Quickest way to check for pre-existing record before insert [mysql_errno()]

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, insert, unique-constraint

My question will use emails as an example, but this could apply to anything.

---

Normally before registering a new user (including inserting his/her email) I check if his/her email already exists in the DB something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)"';");
if(!$result)
{
    die(mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    die('<p>Email already in DB. <a....>Recover Email</a></p>');
}
else
{
    //insert new user data into Users table
}
```

---

Since I'd have constrained the `email` field in my Users table to be `UNIQUE` anyway, wouldn't it be quicker to try to insert first and if it fails, check the error? Something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);//insert new user data into Users table
if(!$result)
{
    if(mysql_errno()==$insert_unique_error)
    {
        $error = '<p>Email already in DB. <a....>Recover Email</a></p>';
    }
    else
    {
        $error = mysql_error();
    }
    die($die_str);
}
```

The problem is that I don't know **what `$insert_unique_error` should be**. These are the only error codes [I could find](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-types.html):

> The first two characters of an SQLSTATE value indicate the error class:
>
> Class = '00' indicates success.
>
> Class = '01' indicates a warning.
>
> Class = '02' indicates “not found.” This is relevant within the context of cursors and is used to control what happens when a cursor reaches the end of a data set. This condition also occurs for SELECT ... INTO var_list statements that retrieve no rows.
>
> Class > '02' indicates an exception.

Comment: You're still doing one single query, so why that?

Comment: @DamienPirsy In the normal way I do two queries when the email doesn't already exist (select + insert) and one when it does (select). The solution I suggested would only do one query whether the email exists or not (insert).

Comment: I'm thinking it's:

    Error: 1092 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_INSERT_INFO) 

    Message: Records: %ld Duplicates: %ld Warnings: %ld

You mail field should be UNIQUE.

Comment: @DamienPirsy I just realized I forgot to edit a part after I copied and pasted it. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Users VALUES(...);
```

with a unique key on email field, then check row count with mysql_affected_rows();

This will result in a single query to the DB and rule out the race condition of the time window between SELECT and INSERT

Comment: Of course, `mysql_affected_rows()`, ugh. Why `INSERT IGNORE ...` and not just `INSERT ...`? Is that the specific part/keyword which rules out race conditions?

Comment: INSERT will make the query fail, if it encounters a duplicate key, but INSERT IGNORE will make it succeed while ignoring the row. You could use both, but for my liking having a query fail deliberately is not the best style.

Comment: I don't see the importance in the difference between the two. If I'm going to use `mysql_affected_rows()` then I won't check `if(!$result)` anyway so it doesn't bother me whether it succeeded/failed, I'm just going to check the affected rows. Right? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: If the query failed, you don't get a valid mysql_affected_rows(). In this case you need to check the error code instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that COUNT is one of the quickest methods.  Also remember when doing your queries, if you only want to test its existence don't do a

```
SELECT *
```

Instead specify a specific field

```
SELECT id
```

So you are not retrieving as much data. In the case of using COUNT:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Users WHERE email = 'emailaddress'
```

Please see below link on how to use COUNT in a result set

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php

Comment: I agree with using `ID` instead of `*` (I do that normally, just forgot to put it in the question) and `COUNT()` might be quicker than `mysql_num_rows()` but I'm really looking to avoid a `SELECT` altogether.

Comment: Ah fair enough, although it requires an extra query (and less lean code) I prefer to use the select first rather than relying on errors being thrown on insert as it is cleaner and to me seems more logical.  I've not actually come across a situation yet where the extra select adds too much overhead